# NetworkX generating a complete graph from a list of nodes

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have been using NetworkX to find maximal cliques in a graph.  I am trying to take these cliques, and create new graphs, which I then want to add new nodes and edges to.

```
max_cliques = list(nx.find_cliques(mygraph)) //outputs list of lists of cliques
for clique in max_cliques:
    mygraph = nx.Graph()
    mygraph.add_nodes_from(clique)
    mygraph = nx.complete_graph(clique)
```

When I do this, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.

I don't really follow, because the networkx docs say this about complete_graph's parameters:

- `n` (int or iterable container of nodes) – If `n` is an integer, nodes
  are from `range(n)`. If `n` is a container of nodes, those nodes appear
  in the graph.
- `create_using` (Graph, optional (default None)) – If provided this
  graph is cleared of nodes and edges and filled with the new graph.
  Usually used to set the type of the graph.

I've tried a few variations of this but they all give me the same error if I try to use an iterable to populate my complete graph.  Can someone fill me in on what Iam doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what's going on without seeing your input data. If we set `mygraph = nx.karate_club_graph()`, for example, the code runs with no errors.

Comment: Which versions of Python and NetworkX are you running? And what is the inital value of `mygraph`?

Comment: The initial value of mygraph, before finding a given clique, was just another random collection of nodes.  Im not sure why it matters.  When initializing a new graph "mygraph", it's just the collection of nodes that make up that clique.  For example, [0, 9, 14, 22, 28].  So let's say that is my input data.  I'll append this specific example and version info to the end of my post.

Comment: Nevermind.  J.S led me to the solution.

It was an old version of NetworkX.  I have no idea why or how, but updating it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was using an old version of NetworkX.  I upgraded to 2.1, and it now works.